# total and subtotal on the same row

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store some items. These items can be of four types (1,2,3,4) and each item can be open (status=1 or 2) or closed (status=3).

I want to build a dataset where I have for each type the count of how many items are in status 3 and the total amount of items for that type. I have no problems to extract these informations separately (`SELECT count(id), type FROM table WHERE status=3 GROUP BY type` and `SELECT count(id), type FROM table GROUP BY type`) but I would like to have them side by side. I was wondering to join the two tables by type but maybe there is an easier way to do it?
Note: running mysql 8

| id | type | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 | 3 |

| Type | closed | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try to use the condition aggregate function to add conditions to the aggregate function.

```
SELECT Type,
    SUM(distinct status = 3) closed,
    COUNT(*) total
FROM T
GROUP BY Type
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f72086f5ef06a4e55ccda6c1a7afd2af)